# Why is input_length needed in layers.Embedding in keras tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reshape, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

layers.embedding has a parameter (input_length) that the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) describes as:

> input_length : Length of input sequences, when it is constant. This argument is required if you are going to connect Flatten then Dense layers upstream (without it, the shape of the dense outputs cannot be computed).

Why is it that the shape of dense outputs cannot be computed. To me, `Flatten` seems pretty easy to do. It is just a `tf.rehshape(input,(-1,1))` followed by a dense layer with whatever output shape we choose.

Can you help me point to the lapse in my understanding of the entir logic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By specifying the dimension, you're making sure the model receives fixed-length input.

Technically, you can just put `None` at any input dimension you want. The shape will be inferred at run-time.

You only need to make sure you're specifying the layer parameters (input_dim, output_dim), kernel_size (for conv layers), units (for FC layers).

The shape can be computed if you use `Input` and specify what shape of tensor will be passed through the network.

For example following model is perfectly valid:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models

ip = layers.Input((10))
emb = layers.Embedding(10, 2)(ip)
flat = layers.Flatten()(emb)
out = layers.Dense(5)(flat)

model = models.Model(ip, out)

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 10, 2)             20        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 20)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 5)                 105       
=================================================================
Total params: 125
Trainable params: 125
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here, I didn't specify the input_length but it was inferred from the `Input` layer.

**The problem is with Sequential API, if you don't specify the input shape in the Input layer and also not in the embedding layer, there's no way the model can be built with the proper set of parameters.**

For example,

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(10, 2, input_length = 10)) # will be an error if I don't specify input_length here as there is no way to know the shape of the next layers without knowing the length

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(5))


model.summary()
```

In this example, you must specify the input_length, otherwise the model will throw error.

Comment: Thank you for help kind friend! Am i understanding this correct: "input_length : Length of input sequences, when it is constant. This argument is required if you are going to connect Flatten then Dense layers upstream (without it, the shape of the dense outputs cannot be computed)." means that if i am going to attach `flatten` then dense to the output of `embeddings` layer then i have to specify `input_length` parameter. I guess it would be best if you provided me with an example with it was necessary to provide the `input_length` parameter.

Comment: input_length is equivalent to `Input(shape = (10))`, I showed a functional API model where due to my poinitng out the shape previously in the Input layer I didn't have to again specify the length in Embedding, I added a Sequential example, where if I don't specify the input_lenth, the model will throw error as there is no way to select the weight shape for the model. In the end of the day, NN is bucnh of matrices with numbers, and you need to know the dimension of each matrices before building a model.

Comment: That makes sense. But, dont we build the layers in `build` method lazily? The weights would be computed based upon the first input batch?

Comment: Each time you instantiate a layer object, it either gets the shape directly (input layer), or infers from the previous layer, If no relevant shape information is found, it throws error. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer
Think this way, the Dense is a fully connected layer, so it needs to know how many inputs are there in the previous layer (because in dense, every input is connected to every output), otherwise it can't initialize the weight matrix.

Comment: Ohhhh yes! I see. It's akin to not specifying the output shape of the previous dense layer and then expecting the next layer to create its weights. However, i still have a wrinkle.. The situation where the output shape of previous dense layer is not specified remains ambiguous even after the first batch is passed through the network. But this situation can easily be handled by creating the weights in `build` method. I do not think the model weights are initialized when the model is compiled anyway. Your second network has all weights known deterministically the moment the first batch is passed

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The weights are assigned just at the model I call `model = Model(ip, op)`. To verify that you can even try `model.get_weights()` just after calling model = Model(ip, op), you don't even need to compile it. That's how libraries are designed and it's the only logical way.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But models are compiled before model is called and model call calls build the first time it is called. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#best_practice_deferring_weight_creation_until_the_shape_of_the_inputs_is_known . Basically the weights are created the first time the model is called

Comment: from tensorflow guide linked in previous comment: `linear_layer = Linear(32)`  # At instantiation, we don't know on what inputs this is going to get called
`y = linear_layer(x)`  # The layer's weights are created dynamically the first time the layer is called

Comment: Yes, and the model will be built with weights, to know the weights, you need proper shape information. I'm not following you right now on the discussion. Why do you think not specifying input_length is useful?

Comment: Ohh .. apologies i havent been able to explain myself properly. I think shape information can be got at the first run of the model and this is the idiomatic way to build weights as recommended by tensorflow. I think not specifying the input_length could be useful in case you wanted to build a generic netowork that could be used for different use cases (different sequence length). Very much the same motivation that has led to the current semantics of creating weights lazily in the build method. If tensorflow lazily creates weights in `Linear(32)(x)` then why is input_shape made mendatory?

Comment: Not specifying the input shape works for regular layers like Conv, LSTM. I told it already in the answer, you can specify None as the input shape. But anything that comes before Dense must have proper shape information. That's how Dense works and you can't change the shape in the run time, in Dense the input is multiplied with the weight vector, the dimensions must match and agree.

Comment: That is how the Dense works i understand now. But, i do not understand yet why it is the logical way. If i can do `tf.random.set_seed(42)` `rd=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)` `print(rd.variables)#[]` `rd(np.array([[1.]],dtype=np.float32))` `print(rd.variables)#[<tf.Variable 'dense_18/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.5700599]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_18/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]` ..Then why is the previous shape needed for a dense layer. But apparently it is. Which is why they have mentioned the dense layer specifically

Comment: Thank you for taking so much trouble! You are very kind